# Font won't embed in MS WORD

Tags: fonts, microsoft-word-2010

I have a font that is an OpenType Postscript font and I realize that it cannot be embedded into the word document. I have tried to create a screenshot of the part of the document that I would like to have the font but when I do that it looks terrible. This document needs to be printed and it needs to be an editable form so that spaces change if more space is needed on the page. I have looked into making a pdf form but if I do that, then everything is set in place and no space can be added. Is there any other way to do this?

I am working in Word 2010

I am trying to use the form on multiple computers where the computers do not have the font installed and I may not be able to get to the computer to install the font. But I would also like to make sure that if someone else was to open the file they would see everything correctly.

Comment: What makes you think you cannot embed the font into the document?

Comment: It is not possible. See my answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill - You answered my question.  You didn't address the author's secondary question of, is there another way to accomplish what they are trying to do, since OpenType PS fonts cannot be embedded into a Word document?

Comment: @Ramhound It is not clear what he is trying to do, since you don't need to embed a font to use it in a document or print the document. If the OP clarifies this I will address it in my answer (if possible).

Comment: @DavidPostill - Yeah;  I realize what he is trying to do is not clear, I guess given the current the title of the question your answer does indeed answer the question.

Comment: You don't need to embed a font to use it in a document or print the document. Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do, and why whatever this is requires an embedded font.

Answer (score 1):

#### I have an OpenType Postscript font and it cannot be embedded into a Word document.

It is not possible to embed OpenType Postscript fonts.

You can only embed TrueType fonts into word documents.

There are also additional restrictions on embedding TrueType fonts. See below.

---

#### How to embed a TrueType font in a document

> Not all fonts are licensed so that they can be embedded. If a font can
>   be embedded, it will increase the file size of your document by
>   approximately the size of the TrueType font (.ttf) file.
>
> NOTE: Some fonts treat normal, bold, italic, and bold-italic as
>   separate font .ttf files. In this case, the file size of your document
>   is larger when you use bold and italic formatting than it is if you do
>   not.
>
> If a font does not have a bold, italic, or bold-italic version,
>   Windows generates bold or italic from the core font. In this case, the
>   file size increases when you use bold or italic formatting.
>
> Licensing rights for font embedding determine how the font may be
>   embedded in the document.

[image]

Source [How to embed a TrueType font in a document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290952)

---

#### Embedding Fonts in a Document

> Word allows you to embed fonts in your document, with a couple of
>   caveats.
>
> First of all, the fonts must be TrueType fonts, and second, they must
>   be available for embedding.
>
> Figuring out if a font is TrueType is easy enough—you can take a look
>   at the Windows Font folder to figure that out, or you can simply look
>   for the telltale TT next to the font name in Word's Font drop-down
>   list.
>
> Figuring out if a font is embeddable is another issue. When a font is
>   created, by the designer, it can be set to one of four levels of
>   embedding compatibility:
>
> - Fully Embeddable. These will embed in the document and install themselves on the target system if they do not already exist there.
> - Editable Embedding. The document is editable in the embedded font, but will not permanently install on the target system.
> - Print and Preview Only. The document will print with the correct font on the target system, but it is not editable and the font will
>     not install.
> - Not Embeddable. The font stays on the original system and cannot be embedded in a document.
>
> Word respects the wishes of the font designer, according to the
>   possible settings show here. If a designer marks a font as "not
>   embeddable," then you cannot embed it in a document. More precisely,
>   you can instruct Word to embed TrueType fonts, but Word ignores your
>   instruction when it comes to the font that is marked as not
>   embeddable.

Source [Embedding Fonts in a Document](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T006073_Embedding_Fonts_in_a_Document.html)

Comment: I have found this information and I do know that the font is under the category of "Editable Embedding"

Comment: @user3230051 It still **has to be a TrueType font**. The compatibilty/licensing restrictions are for **TrueType** fonts.

Comment: I know that it has to be a TrueType font or a certain kind of OpenType font(don't remember what the rules are right now) but is there any other way of getting the text on the page? I've tried making it an image but it comes out not as clear.

Comment: You don't need to embed a OpenType font to use it in a document or print the document. See [Use OpenType to Beautify Fonts in Word 2010 & 2013](http://projectwoman.com/2013/10/use-opentype-to-beautify-fonts-in-word-2010-2013.html) and [Using OpenType Fonts in Moscrosft Word](http://www.magpiepaperworks.com/blog/using-opentype-fonts-in-microsoft-word/). If you cannot install the font then you **have to choose a different font**.

Comment: I am aware of this and the font is installed on only this computer not any others. I am trying to use the document on another computer which is the problem because the fonts are not installed on any other computer besides this one.

Comment: I can't help you with that.

Comment: Fair enough. I have not found a solution after researching all day so I have created a script that checks for the font and gives a message box if the font is not installed with instructions on how to install the font.